# How do I convert a pandas pivot table to a JSON

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I created a table like below using pandas pivot table.

```
print(pd_pivot_table)

category_id  name
3            name3        0.329204
24           name24       0.323727
31           name31       0.319526
19           name19       0.008992
23           name23       0.005897
```

I want to create JSON based on this pivot_table, but I do not know how.

```
[
  {
    "category_id": 3,
    "name": "name3",
    "score": 0.329204
  },
  {
    "category_id": 24,
    "name": "name24",
    "score": 0.323727
  },
  {
    "category_id": 31,
    "name": "name31",
    "score": 0.319526
  },
  {
    "category_id": 19,
    "name": "name19",
    "score": 0.008992
  },
  {
    "category_id": 23,
    "name": "name23",
    "score": 0.005897
  }
]
```

Or, I do not know how to get category_id and name values in the first place.
Even if you write the code below you can not get the results you want.

```
for data in pd_pivot_table:
  print(data) # 0.329204
  print(data["category_id"]) # *** IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) first for `DataFrame` and then [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
print (df)
category_id  name  
3            name3     0.329204
24           name24    0.323727
31           name31    0.319526
19           name19    0.008992
23           name23    0.005897
Name: score, dtype: float64

print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

json = df.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
print (json)
[{"category_id":3,"name":"name3","score":0.329204},
 {"category_id":24,"name":"name24","score":0.323727},
 {"category_id":31,"name":"name31","score":0.319526},
 {"category_id":19,"name":"name19","score":0.008992},
 {"category_id":23,"name":"name23","score":0.005897}]
```

If need output to file:

```
df.reset_index().to_json('file.json',orient='records')
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.reset_index())
   category_id    name     score
0            3   name3  0.329204
1           24  name24  0.323727
2           31  name31  0.319526
3           19  name19  0.008992
4           23  name23  0.005897

print (type(df.reset_index()))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```